# How could python treat unicode and non-unicode tuple as equal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am using Python 2.7.11.

I have 2 tuples:

```
>>> t1 = (u'aaa', u'bbb')
>>> t2 = ('aaa', 'bbb')
```

And I tried this:

```
>>> t1==t2
True
```

How could Python treat unicode and non-unicode the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 2 considers bytestrings and unicode equal.  By the way, this has nothing to do with the containing tuple.  Instead it's to do with an implicit type-conversion, which I will explain below.

It's difficult to demonstrate it with 'easy' ascii codepoints, so to see what really goes on under the hood, we can provoke a failure by using higher codepoints:

```
>>> bites = u'Ç'.encode('utf-8')
>>> unikode = u'Ç'
>>> print bites
Ç
>>> print unikode
Ç
>>> bites == unikode
/Users/wim/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ipython:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  #!/usr/bin/python
False
```

On seeing a unicode and bytes comparison above, python has implicitly attempted to decode the bytestring to a unicode object by making an assumption that the bytes were encoded with `sys.getdefaultencoding()` (which is 'ascii' on my platform).

In the case I just showed above, this failed, because the bytes were encoded in 'utf-8'.  Now, let's make it "work":

```
>>> bites = u'Ç'.encode('ISO8859-1')
>>> unikode = u'Ç'
>>> import sys
>>> reload(sys)   # please don't ever actually use this hack, guys 
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> sys.setdefaultencoding('ISO8859-1')
>>> bites == unikode
True
```

Your upconversion "works" in pretty much the same way, but using an 'ascii' codec.  These kind of implicit conversions between bytes and unicode are actually pretty evil and can cause a lot of [pain](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), so it was decided to stop doing those in Python 3 because "explicit is better than implicit".

As a minor digression, on Python 3+ your code is actually both representing unicode string literals so they are equal anyway.  The u prefix is silently ignored.  If you want a bytestring literal in python3, you need to specify it like `b'this'`.  Then you would want to either 1) explicitly decode the bytes, or 2) explicitly encode the unicode object before making a comparison.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.